# Crear filtro en excel desde C# usando Interop

Tags: c#, excel

[image: Excel sin filtro]

En la cabecera quiero que aparezca el filtro una vez creado el documento en excel.

He probado varias opciones y combinaciones, pero **NO** me han funcionado.

Opción 1:

```
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "J1");
oRng.AutoFilter("1", "<>", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, "", true);
```

Opcion 2:

```
oSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1;
oSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
oRng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)oSheet.Rows[1];
oRng.AutoFilter(1, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);
```

Los errores que me dan son los siguientes:

> 1- "No se pudo completar la operación para el rango de celdas
>   seleccionado. Seleccione una única celda dentro del rango e inténtelo
>   de nuevo."
>
> 2- "Error en el método AutoFilter de la clase Range."

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te convenga probar la primera opción, con un rango de una celda:

```
oSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1")
```

Comment: Lo he probado y me daba error igual.

Comment: Lo probé con get_Range("A1") y después, AutoFilter(1), sin agregar los demás parámetros, y andaba... pero estas cosas son bastante variables entre instalaciones

Answer (score -1):

Para seleccionar rango es así `hoja.get_Range("G:G",Type.Missing);` para seleccionar una columna completa o en tu caso debiese ser `sheet.get_Range("A1:J1",Type.Missing)`